# Magento change billing address sequence

Tags: billing-address

On Magento orders and invoices the seguence is city, state, postal code.
I'm living in Holland and I would like to change it on orders and invoices to
postcal code,  city, state

Example L.A., California, Beverly Hills 91210 would change to  Beverly Hills 91210, LA , California

Can somebody please explain how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change all the customer address templates at:

```
System > Config > Customer > Customer configuration > Address Templates
```

Comment: Wow working several years with Magento but didn't know this option, thanx !